# CryptoJS AES encrypt & C# AES Decrypt causes IV block size error

Tags: c#, aes, cryptojs

I'm getting "Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm" when trying to decrypt on C# using **System.Security.Cryptography.AES**.

I encrypt with Crypto-JS:

```
var key = CryptoJS.MD5("secret");
var iv = CryptoJS.MD5("deviceID");

encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(pass, key, {iv:iv, mode:CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding:CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 }).toString();  
decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {iv:iv, mode:CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding:CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Decrypt with C#:

```
byte[] iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hexIv);
byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hexKey);
byte[] cipher = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sCipher);

using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
{
    aes.Key = key;
    aes.IV = iv; // HERE I GOT ERROR (IV) does not match the block size

    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
    
    using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
    {
        using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
            {
                try
                {
                    decrypted = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

C# iv is a 32 bytes size
Both IV's are the same MD5 hash

[AES Object Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk7bQ.png)

Comment: If in the C# code `hexIv` and `hexKey` are hex encoded, then they must be hex decoded and not UTF-8 encoded. And analogously a Base64 encoded ciphertext must be Base64 decoded and not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Thanks... it helps to set the IV correctly, but now decryptor is returning a empty string.
I am working on it.

Comment: These settings are extremely weak. You should use [PBKDF2](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#pbkdf2) to securely hash passwords. .NET implements PBKDF2 through the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-7.0) class